# Partial Views using data grids

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to call in two partial views but my program is trying to populate my web grid before I pass it a search parameter. I can't figure out how to keep it from trying to render the webgrid before I pass it the text in the searchbox. 
This is in my partial view:

```
<div class="webgrid-wrapper">
    <div class="webgrid-title">Values</div>
    <div id="grid">
        @grid.GetHtml(
tableStyle: "webgrid",
        headerStyle: "webgrid-header",
        footerStyle: "webgrid-footer",
        alternatingRowStyle: "webgrid-alternating-rows",
        columns: grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("Id", "ID"),
            grid.Column("Name", "Name")
        )
        )
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is my Home view where I'm pulling both of the partial views into:

```
    <section class="featured">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <hgroup class="title">
            <h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
            <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </div>
</section>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Analysis", "Home", "POST"))
{
<div class="searchField">
    <div class="searchbox">
        Search: <input type="text" name="Search" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
}


 @Html.Partial("PartialChemAnalysis")
 @Html.Partial("PartialSlagView")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by checking the search parameter if it has a value, if no, then you dont have to render the grid.

in your controller

```
public ViewResult Analysis(string search) {
        ViewBag.DisplayGrid = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(search);
        //do you logics then return
    }
```

in your view

```
  @if (ViewBag.DisplayGrid != null && ViewBag.DisplayGrid) {
        //Render your partial since its true.
          @Html.Partial("PartialChemAnalysis")
          @Html.Partial("PartialSlagView")
     }
```

upon initial load or if there are no search parameter. the viewbag will be set to false, and your partial will not be rendered.
and will rendered if the search parameter has value.